# BehaviorSubject.value is undefined and BehaviorSubject.next() is not a function

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I'm having trouble with BehaviorSubjects.
in gallery.component.ts there are 3 BehaviorSubject like @Input, for the moment I'm trying to make "brands" work which I log into the console in ngOnInit() with a setTimeout and it returns "undefined" but the same used in the html template gives me the values that I expect.
Also when I try to give "this.brands.next (brands)" in the "checkboxChange()" function it gives me this error: "this.brands.next () is not a function".

I suppose the problem is in the @Input step, because the same code, in another project that doesn't use @Inputs, works correctly.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/AndreaDiCioccio/NewCarsMarketPlace?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fgallery%2Fgallery.component.ts) and [github](https://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NewCarsMarketPlace) links

**gallery.component.ts**

```
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() allCars:BehaviorSubject<Car[]>
    @Input() brands:BehaviorSubject<BrandCB[]>
    @Input() types:BehaviorSubject<TypeCB[]>

    filteredCars:BehaviorSubject<Car[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Car[]>(null)

    checkboxBrandAll:boolean = true
    checkboxTypeAll:boolean = true

    ngOnInit():void{
        this.filteredCars = this.allCars
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('onInit brands:', this.brands.value)
        }, 5000);
        
        //this.filterCars()
    }
 
    checkboxChange(event):void{
        
        let name = event.target.name;
        let checked = event.target.checked;
        
        console.log('brands', this.brands.value)

        //BRANDS
        let brands:BrandCB[] = this.brands.value;

        if(name =='allBrands'){
        
            brands.map(brand => brand.checked = false);

            this.brands.next(brands);

        } else if(name == 'otherBrands'){

            if(checked == true){

                this.checkboxBrandAll = false;

            } else {

                let isOneChecked:boolean = false;
                brands.map(brand => brand.checked ? isOneChecked = true : null)

                if(!isOneChecked)
                    this.checkboxBrandAll = true;

            }

            this.brands.next(brands);
        
        }

        // TYPES
        let types:TypeCB[] = this.types.value;

        if(name =='allTypes'){
    
            types.map(type => type.checked = false)
        
            this.types.next(types);

        } else if(name == 'otherTypes'){

            if(checked == true){

                this.checkboxTypeAll = false;

            } else {

                let isOneChecked:boolean = false;
                types.map (type => type.checked ? isOneChecked = true : null)

                if(!isOneChecked)
                this.checkboxTypeAll = true;

            }

            this.types.next(types);
        
        }

        this.filterCars();

    }
}
```

**gallery.component.html**

```
<div class="conteiner">

    <div class="left-conteiner">
        <div class="filter-box-brand">
            <div class="filterLabel"><b>Brand</b></div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="allBrands" name="allBrands" value="all" 
                [(ngModel)]="checkboxBrandAll" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> all
            </label>
            <div class="checkboxList" *ngFor="let brand of (brands | async)">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{brand.name}}" name="otherBrands" value="{{brand.name}}"
                    [(ngModel)]="brand.checked" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> {{brand.name}}
                </label>
                <label class="labelCount"> ({{brand.count}})</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="filter-box-type">
            <div class="filterLabel"><b>Type</b></div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="allType" name="allTypes" value="all" [(ngModel)]="checkboxTypeAll" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> all</label>
            <div class="checkboxList" *ngFor="let type of (types | async)">
                <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="type.checked" id="{{type.name}}" name="otherTypes" value="{{type.name}}" (change)="checkboxChange($event)"> {{type.name}}</label><label class="labelCount"> ({{type.count}})</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="central-conteiner">
        <div class="gallery" >
            <app-car-card-gallery *ngFor="let car of (filteredCars | async)" [car]="car"></app-car-card-gallery>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Having a BehaviorSubject as an `@Input` variable seems like wrong design. If you want to share data b/n components either use `@Input` with Javascript primitives and objects or use a common `BehaviorSubject` in a singleton service.

Comment: You pass Observable type to Input which is BehaviorSubject type. The observable type does not have the next() method so the error is correct. You should change your logic and fix types.